# dnsmasq doesn't automatically reload when entry is added to /etc/hosts

Tags: dnsmasq

I am struggling for a few days to configure dnsmasq to automatically reload or take into knowledge the new hosts added to /etc/hosts or to another configured file `/etc/hosts.dnsmasq`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Nope. Interestingly, it can poll `/etc/resolv.conf` for changes, but not `/etc/hosts`. You could use an inotify to trigger SIGHUP or service reload.

Comment: The thing is that in my project, the hosts will be changed like a few times per minute. This will make dnsmasq restart a few times per minute. Is this a very bad problem?

Comment: Consider a "proper" DNS server with a database backend that takes live changes.

Comment: @AaronCopley which one, for example?

Comment: If you really want changes that frequent, wouldn't you be better of using dhcp? dnsmasq will happily (and automatically) serve hostnames received that way

Answer (score 13):

There are two ways to cause dnsmasq to reload a hosts file:

1. As Aaron Copley [noted in his comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/723292/dnsmasq-doesnt-automatically-reload-when-entry-is-added-to-etc-hosts#comment900157_723292), send `SIGHUP` to dnsmasq. From the [man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html#lbAG):

   > When it receives a SIGHUP, **dnsmasq** clears its cache and then re-loads */etc/hosts* and */etc/ethers* and any file given by --dhcp-hostsfile, --dhcp-hostsdir, --dhcp-optsfile, --dhcp-optsdir, --addn-hosts or --hostsdir. The dhcp lease change script is called for all existing DHCP leases. If **--no-poll** is set SIGHUP also re-reads */etc/resolv.conf*. SIGHUP does NOT re-read the configuration file.

   Note that dnsmasq doesn't restart in this case, but it does re-read a number of other files (and calls the dhcp lease change script for  all existing DHCP leases). If triggering reloads too quickly is a concern, you can [debounce](https://medium.com/ghostcoder/debounce-vs-throttle-vs-queue-execution-bcde259768) the signal.
2. Use the `--hostsdir` option. Again from the [man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html#lbAE):

   > **--hostsdir=<path>**
   >           Read all the hosts files contained in the directory. New or changed files are read automatically. See --dhcp-hostsdir for details.

   For reference, here is the documentation for `--dhcp-hostsdir`:

   > **--dhcp-hostsdir=<path>**
   >           This is equivalent to dhcp-hostsfile, except for the following. The path MUST be a directory, and not an individual file. Changed or new files within the directory are read automatically, without the need to send SIGHUP. If a file is deleted or changed after it has been read by dnsmasq, then the host record it contained will remain until dnsmasq receives a SIGHUP, or is restarted; ie host records are only added dynamically.

   This has a few advantages compared to the first option: dnsmasq will re-read the host file(s) automatically, no `SIGHUP` required, and; only the host files are reloaded, no other actions are taken.

   One potential disadvantage is that, as the documentation for `--dhcp-hostsdir` points out, new host entries are dynamically added but deleted or changed entries are not updated. Simon Kelley, the author of dnsmasq, has [confirmed that this is by design](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=798653#35).

Comment: To respond to the latter comment... it is by lack of design - he was too lazy to implement just a diff... let's see who gets around to it first... if it turns out to be necessary.