# Libvirt guest hostnames DNS resolution from host and guests

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, dnsmasq

I have set up multiple virtual machines with libvirt and kvm on Ubuntu server 20.04, which work just as expected. The only thing I cannot figure out at this point is how to make their hostnames resolvable between the guests and from the host, at the moment I can only access them via their ip addresses which I can get from `virsh net-dhcp-leases default`.

I'd like to access the virtual machines by their hostname or similar both from the host and from within the virtual machines, as relying on these ip addresses is a bit inconvenient, but am not sure how to achieve this. I have tried following articles such as [this](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2017/03/03/howto-automated-dns-resolution-for-kvmlibvirt-guests-with-a-local-domain/). If a host is named `test` I want it to be reachable by both `test` and `test.example.com`, while `external.example.com` is not resolved to an internal address, but an external one possibly somewhere else, which I think could be a problem with the solution in the article above. Would this be best achieved by adding entries manually in the hosts `/etc/hosts` or by something similar in the article above? I have tried adding entries to the `/etc/hosts/` file but the entries have only worked on the host machine, but I assume that it is because I haven't properly set up dnsmasq or something similar.

Any help will be appreciated, since I am very much a confused beginner and it is quite overwhelming.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/723292/126632

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libvirt provides a `nss` module which you can configure on the host, which uses the `net-dhcp-leases` information to provide host resolution https://libvirt.org/nss.html

Comment: this looks promising! at the moment i have solved it using dnsmasq via networkmanager, where i manually input entries for each vm, which isn't a big deal since i have very few guests, but is more to maintain

Comment: works pretty much as i want it, only thing that i'd like to get working is accessing the guests both from `test` and `test.example.com` given that the hostname is `test`

Comment: also ran into an issue where docker containers, even in host network mode dont seem to recognize the hostnames. possibly docker / docker network not using nsswitch.conf?